# How do I encrypt special characters or numbers using AES-256?

Tags: go, encryption, aes, mql4

I would like to encrypt a string in Go using AES-256, without any GCM processing, to compare against MQL4. I encounter issues when I try to encrypt special characters or numbers. Should I be pre-processing my plaintext somehow? I am new to Go so any help would be appreciated; my code is below this explanation.

If I encrypt the plaintext "This is a secret" and then decrypt the ciphertext (encoded to hex), I get the same result (i.e. "This is a secret"). pt is the variable name of the plaintext in the code below.

If I try to encrypt "This is a secret; 1234", the ciphertext has a group of zeroes at the end, and when I decrypt I only get "This is a secret". Similar ciphertext in MQL4 does not have zeroes at the end and decrypts correctly.

If I try to encrypt only "1234", I get build errors, stemming from "crypto/aes.(*aesCipherAsm).Encrypt(0xc0000c43c0, 0xc0000ac058, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc0000ac070, 0x4, 0x8)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/crypto/aes/cipher_asm.go:60 +0x125"

Here is my code:

```js
    package main

    import (
        "crypto/aes"
        "encoding/hex"
        "fmt"
    )

    func main() {

        // cipher key
        key := "thisis32bitlongpassphraseimusing"

        // plaintext
        pt := "This is a secret"
        //  pt := "This is a secret; 1234" // zeroes in ciphertext
        //  pt := "1234" // doesn't build

        c := EncryptAES([]byte(key), pt)

        // plaintext
        fmt.Println(pt)

        // ciphertext
        fmt.Println(c)

        // decrypt
        DecryptAES([]byte(key), c)
    }

    func EncryptAES(key []byte, plaintext string) string {

        c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
        CheckError(err)

        out := make([]byte, len(plaintext))

        c.Encrypt(out, []byte(plaintext))

        return hex.EncodeToString(out)
    }

    func DecryptAES(key []byte, ct string) {
        
      ciphertext, _ := hex.DecodeString(ct)

        c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
        CheckError(err)

        pt := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
        c.Decrypt(pt, ciphertext)

        s := string(pt[:])
        fmt.Println("DECRYPTED:", s)
    }

    func CheckError(err error) {
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite get the code in `EncodeAES`: the documentation on `cipher.Block` states that its `Encrypt` encrypts a single block of the input stream. To cite Wikipedia on what a block cipher is, «…algorithms accept two inputs: an input block of size `n` bits and a key of size `k` bits; and both yield an `n`-bit output block.» In your code, you allocate a destination slice the size of the input text and then hex-encode it as a string _in its entirety_ even though a single block was encoded which might have resulted in less bytes written that the length of the input text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a raw AES encryptor here. AES can only encrypt precisely 16 bytes of plaintext, producing exactly 16 bytes of cipher text. Your first example `"This is a secret"` is exactly 16 bytes long, so it works as expected. Your second example is too long. Only the first 16 bytes are being encrypted. The third example is too short and you're likely running into uninitialized memory.

The specific characters in your text are irrelevant. Encryption is performed on raw bytes, not letters.

In order to encrypt larger (or smaller) blocks of text, you need to use a block cipher mode on top of AES. Common modes are GCM, CBC, and CTR, but there are many others. In most cases, when someone says "AES" without any qualifier, they mean AES-CBC. (GCM is becoming much more popular, and it's a great mode, but it's not so popular that it's assumed quite yet.)

I don't know anything about MQL4, but I assume you're trying to reimplement [CryptEncode](https://docs.mql4.com/common/cryptencode)? I don't see any documentation on how they do the encryption. You need to know what mode they use, how they derive their key, how they generate (and possibly encode) their IV, whether they include an HMAC or other auth, and more. You need to know exactly how they implement whatever they mean by "CRYPT_AES256." There is no one, standard answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

MQL4 only supports a very specific implementation of AES encryption and unless you use the correct settings in your other code you will not achieve compatibility between the two platforms.

Specifically you need to ensure the following are implemented:

- Padding Mode: Zeros
- Cipher Mode: ECB (so no IV)
- KeySize: 256
- BlockSize: 128

You also need to remember in MQL4 that encryption/decryption is a two stage process (to AES256 then to BASE64).

You can try the online AES encryption/decryption tool to verify your results available here: [The online toolbox](https://the-x.cn/en-us/cryptography/Aes.aspx)

Comment: FTR: ECB is just independent encryption of each message block. It is insecure for many reasons ([it can't even hide penguins](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption)). Because ECB is trivial to implement and insecure there is no direct support in Go's standard library.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately MetaTrader 4 only supports 128bit & 256bit AES or 56bit DES encryption.

Comment: Thanks. The accepted answer helped with my immediate query, this answer precluded a follow-up. I have got MQL4 and Go output to agree with each other. Unfortunately they do not agree with the online toolbox, which looks like a good resource. Probably a matter of tweaking the toolbox options.